# Javascript are these calls the same in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering if these two blocks of code are the same in **Node.js**?

```
// Style 1
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('hello');
}, 0);


// Style 2
console.log('hello');
```

Since above I'm passing `0` for the timeout, there should be no waiting time. Is it identical to just calling `console.log('hello');` directly without using setTimeout?

Comment: @Quentin would this make any difference for Node.js specific?

Comment: @Quentin, so are you saying that setTimeout 0 in my case Node.js will be the same? Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Yes. Node.js will treat JavaScript like JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are different, the first adds the function to the event queue, so that it can execute as soon as it gets a chance after the current execution path completes. The second will execute it immediately.

For example:

```
console.log('first');

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('third');
}, 0);

console.log('second');
```

The order that those are printed in is well defined, you could even do something slow (but synchronous) before printing 'second'. It's guaranteed that `console.log('second');` will still execute before the callback to [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html#setTimeout) does:

```
console.log('first');

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('third'); // Prints after 8 seconds
}, 0);

// Spinlock for 3 seconds
(function(start){ while(new Date - start < 3000); })(new Date);

console.log('second'); // Prints after 3 seconds, but still before 'third'

// Spinlock for 5 seconds
(function(start){ while(new Date - start < 5000); })(new Date);
```

Comment: @NamNguyen Yes, it is true for node.js as well as web browsers.

Comment: ic and thanks. so these two function are different, no matter web or node.js. Interesting, learn new thing!

Comment: good stuff. The result of the script will print out in order of: first, second, & third

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you *just* want the behavior described above (on Node.js), [`process.nextTick(...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) is a more efficient alternative to `setTimeout(..., 0)` because it doesn't involve the overhead of timer scheduling.

Answer (score -3):

Strictly speaking they are not exactly the same - setTimeout gives the browser a chance to "catch up" with any tasks that it desperately needs to do. But as far as we're normally concerned, 99% of the time they will do the same thing.